# Maya Python: Getting a Float Slider Group to align in the same row as Checkboxes

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I have a small window I'm building, and I'm having trouble getting a slider group to sit to the immediate right of some check boxes. It simply disappears from the row.

I've made the third column pretty huge to try and accommodate it just in case.

```
def slider_drag_callback(*args): 
    print 'Slider Dragged' 

window = cmds.window() 
cmds.columnLayout() 
cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc=2, cw=[(1, 50), (2, 40), (3, 300)])
cmds.checkBox(l="Trans")
cmds.checkBox(l="Rot")
cmds.floatSliderGrp(label="Sldr", field=True, value=0, dc=slider_drag_callback)

cmds.setParent('..')
cmds.showWindow(window)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, you have the number of columns set to 2, not 3. This is the *nc* argument in rowColumnLayout.

```
cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc=3, cw=[(1, 50), (2, 40), (3, 300)])
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Follow up question...how do I get the slider group to align to the left? It's almost as if it starts on the right of the column and just keeps going. The checkboxes align to the left fine.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really use Maya's UI functions anymore, I use PyQt for everything. However I do know it's difficult to get the alignment to work exactly as you want using row and column layouts, so I would suggest using formLayouts instead and manually setting the attachments and offsets to exactly where you need them. But you try the columnAlign arguments for the layout and the control to see if those solve the issue, sometimes they work, sometimes they don't